# Add a Scroll box in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I've searched the all Internet and didn't come up with a solution. 
well, I have a report for a client which I made it in ssrs.

The report basically display :

```
Col1 Col2 
Num   Num
```

I want to add a Col3 with a scroll box that the client (user) will set "valid" or "not valid". any option to do that ?

Thank's!

Comment: By 'scroll box' do you mean a drop-down box with two choices i.e. you want an interactive control on the report?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A drop-down.

Comment: SSRS is more of a _presentation_ tool so interactive controls aren't available. Apart from creating a custom .NET application that implements the SSRS API, there are 'hacks' that can be done by injecting JavaScript in to the report or using parameterized URLs. Just keep in mind they're a workaround at best. If I have time, I will try to produce an example. I suggest researching JavaScript injection at least.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is validating the data from your report and writing back to a database, I would suggest using MS Excel with VBA to update the database rather than using SSRS, which may not be the correct tool for the job in this instance.